# Ошибка в юнити Download failed: Validation Failed

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-hub

При установке любой версии Unity я получаю ошибку "Download failed: Validation Failed". Я посмотрел много статей и видео, пробовал все, и от имени администратора запускал и Unity archive скачивал, и место установки менял(получил еще больше ошибок)
Что делать в таком случае?
на Windows 10 pro таких проблем не было(сейчас Windows 11 pro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ошибка в unity hub?Есла да то попробуйте использовать ВПН при скачивании(т.к санкции)

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, теперь работает!!!

Answer (score 1):

скачайте не через хаб а отдельно архивом

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]